# restful web service : how to test if item with {id} exists?

Tags: rest, restful-url

**How will you check if item with {Id} exist ?**

1. **POST item/Id** => 404 it does not exist. 409 it exists
2. **GET item/Id** => 404 does not exist. 200 it exists
3. **HEAD item/Id** => 404 does not exist. 200 it exists

I guess the best choice is 3. Unless the HEAD verb is filtered.

Does 1 make any sense ? (Don't remember where I saw this suggestion)
1 could be as well understood as create the item and try to insert it as "Id" in which case it could return a 200 if it succeeds (instead of a 404)

Comment: I don't understand the first one at all. If you're just trying to find out information about whether something exists, attempting to create, overwrite, or add to it seems like a really weird thing to do. What if the POST (or PUT, or PATCH) succeeds rather than giving a 409 CONFLICT error?

Answer (score 3):

> how to test if item with {id} exists?

REST doesn't really have items, it has resources (the resource might refer to an item - but that's really an implementation detail).

Furthermore, "exists" isn't really a concept in REST

> A resource can map to the empty set, which allows references to be made to a concept before any realization of that concept exists -- a notion that was foreign to most hypertext systems prior to the Web

`404` doesn't tell you that a resource doesn't exist - it tells you that there is no currently available *representation* for that resource.  Not precisely the same thing.

That said...

If you are trying to send a message to an origin server about a resource, and want to ensure that doing so causes no damage to property, then the right thing to do is use one of the methods with [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics.

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.

So of your list, `GET` or `HEAD` are appropriate, but not `POST` (because POST doesn't have safe semantics).